# ng-show doesn't show/hide input button

Tags: angularjs

I am implementing an input button, which is visible only if function returns "True" from the back-end.

//Angular Method which returns either true or false, Which is working fine

```
    //Show/Hide Printer
$scope.showHideFunc = function () {
    if ($scope.Foo.id != null && $scope.Foo.id != '') {
       $http.get(getTFfromDBURL + '/' + $scope.Foo.id).success(function 
        (data) {
            $scope.showHide = data;
        });
    }
};
```

//Here is the code for button

```
    <button id="btn-add-device" class="btn btn-info" ng-show="showHide" ng-click="showManagePrinter();loadDrawersForPrinter()">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> {{showHide}}  
            </button>
```

After all its weird at {{showHide}}, where its getting correct values, while its not affecting ng-show="showHide".

Appreciate thoughts.

Thank you.

Comment: Is it even within the scope? Can you show us more of your HTML?

Comment: Is `showHide` always true? are you 100% sure that `data` is returned as a boolean?

Comment: use `console.log(data)`

Comment: Yes Aleksey, it is within a scope.
No, Huangism. Its not true always. if it was there wouldnt be any need of such thing.
And Daniel, I tried console.log(data) too. its returning true/false based on whats stored in DB. Additionally I name that button as {{showHide}}, which is changing too as true or false.

Comment: Are you initializing `$scope.showHide` in the controller? If not, it will be undefined (& falsy), so the button won't show. What exactly is the problem? Something else to consider is that the data returned is probably the STRING `'true'` or STRING `'false'`... so you might need to cast it to a boolean with `$scope.showHide = data === 'true';`